# Restoring the old 'lenny' Debian desktop

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop

In *lenny*, the Debian desktop's default image was the red Debian logo, and it looked like this:

[image]

However, in *squeeze*, the desktop has been replaced by this:

[image]

How can one restory the *lenny* look-and-feel; at least the background image?  Are those graphics still bundled with *squeeze*, and if not, how do I get at them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Durring the release cycle for each successive version of Debian, the community gets to contribute proposals and the default artwork is refined.

The artwork for previous versions is available on the [Debian community wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianDesktop/Artwork/). There is a page collecting the final artwork for each release. For example [lenny artwork is here](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianDesktop/Artwork/Lenny) including a [large version of the default wallpaper](http://www.debianart.org/cchost/people/si0ux/si0ux_-_MoreBlue_Orbit.png) found in your *lenny* screenshot.

You might also be interested in [DebianArtwork.org](http://www.debianart.org/cchost/) where various sizes of released artwork can be found along with many other contributed works and proposals.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!  By the way, the *lenny* desktop wallpaper link is actually [here](http://www.debianart.org/cchost/people/si0ux/si0ux_-_MoreBlue_Orbit.png).